# PHP showing directory folders

Tags: php

Im trying to display all the folders that are in a specific directory. Basically so each time a new folder is added, it will show up automatically on the list. Here is what i have so far. I have pieced this together from other posts and doesn't seem to be working and not sure why. I get a nasty error about permissions and none found.

```
        $dir = '/s/';
        $result = array();

        if (is_dir($dir)) {
                $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
                foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file) {                    
                    if (!$file->isFile()) {
                        $result[] = 'path: ' . $file->getPath(). ',  filename: ' . $file->getFilename();
                    }
                }

        }

        print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that home made code:

```
function collect_files($dir)
{
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        $dir = $dir.'/';
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if(filetype($dir . $file)=='file'){
            $path = strchr($dir,'/');            
            echo "$file - $path<br>\n";
            }
        }
        rewinddir($dh);
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if(filetype($dir . $file)=='dir')
            if($file!='.'&&$file!='..'){
            collect_files($dir.$file);
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
}
collect_files('.');
```